# MyPy: what is the type of a requests object?

Tags: python, python-requests, typechecking, python-3.6, mypy

I'm trying to use Python 3's type hinting syntax, along with the MyPy static type checker. I'm now writing a function that takes a `requests` response object, and I'm wondering how to indicate the type.

That is to say, in the following piece of code, what can I replace `???` with?

```
import requests

def foo(request: ???) -> str:
    return json.loads(request.content)['some_field']

r = requests.get("my_url")
return foo(r)
```

Comment: `type(some_object)` lets you find out the type of an object. Print that and see if you can import it from `requests`. Hint: you can. Also `request.json()` directly does the json loading for you. No need to do it manually.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By using `Response`, either supply the full path to it:

```
def foo(request: requests.models.Response) -> str:
    return json.loads(request.content)['some_field']
```

or, save it to a name of your choice:

```
Response = requests.models.Response

def foo(request: Response) -> str:
    return json.loads(request.content)['some_field']
```

p.s `json.loads` expects a `str`, not `bytes` so you might want to `decode` the `content` first.

Comment: What do i need to import for this to work? I am getting `Name 'requests' is not defined`.

It works if i do `import requests`
but not if I do `from requests import Session`.

What do I need to specify?

Comment: For the above you would want
`from requests import Response`
and foo would be defined as foo(request: Response)

if you just have
`import requests`
foo would be defined as foo(request: requests.models.Response)

Comment: If it wasn't already clear, `requests.Response == requests.models.Response`

Comment: Where is `requests` defined in the Django repo?